# Is there a way to separate selected vertices within the same object

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Is there a way to separate a selection of vertices from a mesh directly without creating a new object?

My current way of doing this is:

- Select vertices
- Use Separate by Selection (<kbd>P</kbd> *> By Selection*)
- Select both objects and join again <kbd>J</kbd>

I feel like there should be a way of doing this completely within edit mode.
Is there?

Comment: yes, using Y or V. The V will work only with selected edges and it cuts out the selection. The Y makes pretty much the same, except if it is not a closed polygon it will just duplicate the vertex or the edge. You cant just take out random vertex because it affect the faces and edges.

Comment: @Fowl ... that looks like an answer, to me.. if it was one, we could UV it.

Comment: @Fowl, Using Y (split command) seems to do what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You want Mesh -> Split -> Selection, which is the <kbd>Y</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Vertex Groups may be what you are after? Found under Context

[image]